# Copy and Filter Data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a small Problem, but i can't solve it

In my Spreadsheet I have a import JSON script.

Example:

```
 | A | B | C | D | E
1| A | Different Content
2| D | Different Content
3| D | Different Content
4| A | Different Content
5| A | Different Content
```

Now I want to copy every line if the content (in line 1 if A=D) to another sheet.
I have to do it in a script because every day there other content.

Comment: Hi i guess you need to explain a little bit more you problem, the json schema getting the schema wanted, the code you tryed to get the resulat.. etc

Comment: okay, sry my englisch isnt that well.So, i have i importet file. No i want to copy a few lines of my importet file, example: i have 20 lines, and i want to copy with an argument, if in the line a field with content=xy i want to copy this on the next free line, and this 4 every line in the next sheet. u know what i mean?

Comment: You could use the filter javascript function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40994602/1595451