# How can I make a JS filter work in the Apps Script API?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use a filter in order to delete some unnecessary data in the fastest possible way.

Unfortunately, I am getting a **syntax error** in the script editor when trying to save the following code:

```
function deleteRows(dataRange){

        var formated = dataRange.filter(e => e[8]||e[9]||e[10]||e[11]||e[12]||e[13]||e[14]||e[15]||e[16]||e[17]||e[18]||e[19]);

     return formated;
    }
```

Does anyone know how can I make the above code work in apps scripts?
Or if the code can't work, what would be the alternative... I am out of ideas...

Comment: Arrow functions doesn't work on Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks, @Rubén. Do you know how can I do this alternatively then?

Comment: Try with an anonymous function.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40994602/1595451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script is at ES 5.1 level, so it has no ES6 features like arrow functions, sets, etc. But the modification is straightforward:

```
function deleteRows(dataRange){
  var formatted = dataRange.filter(function(e) {
    return e[8]||e[9]||e[10]||e[11]||e[12]||e[13]||e[14]||e[15]||e[16]||e[17]||e[18]||e[19];
  });
 return formatted;
}
```